How to integrate Supabase function supabase.composeAuth.rememberSignInWithGoogle() in a ViewModel?
I am trying out Supabase in the android environment. This far I implemented the supabase authentification with Compose Auth and the google sign in and everything works fine. Since I want to use the principals of clean architecture, the functionality of the whole sign in method should not be placed in the composable handling the ui of the sign in screen, but rather in a repository which the corresponding view model injects. Right now the sign in functionality is still in one of my composables because the following function from Compose Auth needs a @Composable context:
val action = supabase.composeAuth.rememberSignInWithGoogle()

Since the functions needs a @Composable context I am not sure how to properly implement this functionality in a view model or in a repository. Can someone help me figure out a way how to handle functions that need a @Composable context regarding clean architecture?
This is the snipped of my composable using the mentioned function:
@Composable
fun SignInScreen(viewModel: SignInViewModel = koinViewModel()) {
val context = LocalContext.current
val client = SupabaseClient

val action = client.supabaseClient.composeAuth.rememberSignInWithGoogle(
    onResult = { result -> //optional error handling
        when (result) {
            is NativeSignInResult.Success -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, "You are signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            is NativeSignInResult.ClosedByUser -> {}
            is NativeSignInResult.Error -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, result.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            is NativeSignInResult.NetworkError -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, result.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    },
    fallback = { // optional: add custom error handling, not required by default

    }
)

    Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
        OutlinedButton(
        onClick = { action.startFlow()},
        content = { ProviderButtonContent(provider = Google)}
    )
}
}

